# How do I return a SQL VIEW in a list

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-view

I made a code returning to a list via a procedure and it worked, but now I need to return a list of a view 
*SQL Server

My code:

```
public List<Ticket> GetTicket()
{
    List<Ticket> ticketList = new List<Ticket>();

    using (_con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from MyView", _con))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;

            _con.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            // reader.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Ticket ticket = new Ticket()
                {
                    //TicketNumber = Convert.ToInt32(reader["numeroTicket"]),
                    Priority= Convert.ToString(reader["tpr_txt_prioridade"]),
                    Status = Convert.ToString(reader["status_descri"]),
                    Client = Convert.ToString(reader["cliente"]),
                    Topic = Convert.ToString(reader["topico"]),
                    Responsible= Convert.ToString(reader["usuario_responsavel"]),
                    OpenDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["dt_int"]),
                    LastInteraction= Convert.ToDateTime(reader["tkt_dat_prazo"])
                };

                ticketList.Add(ticket);
            }
            return ticketList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: `now I need to return a list of a view *SQL Server`, what is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: you sql code "select * from MyView" is ok, is there a runtime error?

Comment: CommandType TableDirect looks suspicious. I believe you just want commandType = Text

Comment: reader["dt_int"] <-- Doing that, if the SQL value is null, it throw an exception, you need to test if reader["dt_int"] != DBNull.Value and if is dbnull put Null value inside of list item, is that what are you asking for? What's the exception you get?

Comment: Do you want to return a List of tickets or what do you mean with a List of SQL View?

Comment: Thanks guys, I was able to solve it, it was just me that changed the CommandType to CommandType.Text

Answer (score -1):

Before

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

After

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

I only had to switch from `.StoredProcedure` to `.Text`

Ty!!!!!!!!!!!